# Possible to perform an "undo" via app script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to cause a 3rd party function (`CRYPTOFINANCE()`) to update whenever I manually trigger an update.  Currently it updates any time I clear the cel contents and hit Undo.  So my thinking is to simply create a script that selects the cells I want to update, clears them, and hits undo.

Unfortunately I can't find any way to execute an undo via script.  Mostly I find references to it not even existing as a function, however I found reference to [`model.undo()`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/undo) which sounds like what I need.  I just can't figure out how to make it work.

My other thought was maybe there is a way to just select the Undo option from the Edit menu via script, but I have a feeling that's not possible either.

Can anyone suggest a way to Undo via script that doesn't involve using a secondary sheet to store the "undo" data?

Comment: At the moment I have solved my need by simply copying the selected range an pasting it over itself again, which results in the same thing I was after via undo.  Still, if anyone knows how to script an Undo, it would be quite useful in other situations.

Comment: Is `CRYPTOFINANCE()` from an add-on, or is it a function you have created?

Comment: It's a 3rd party add-on

Comment: Do you use it by typing it as a function in sheet?

Comment: Yes just like any standard function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script hasn't the undo / redo commands.

NOTE: The Real Time API is not part of Google Apps Script and it's not included in the advanced services.

The alternative is to make the script to keep records of the changes made and if necessary use them to "undo" or "redo" the action.

Comment: OK, that was basically the conclusion I had come to but I wasn't certain about that Real Time API.  I've found a different approach that does what I needed for now anyway... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to refresh the function `CRYPTOFINANCE()` which is entered into any given cell in the sheet, your script would need to do just that.

Using the `getActiveRange()` method, you can programmatically target the cells that you want to refresh. Simply select the cells you want to refresh in the spreadsheet to store them in `range` with the `getActiveRange()` method.

```
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getSheetById(id);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
```

From `range` you can get each individual cell with this:

```
var cell = range.getCell(row, column);
// respectively to the range selected with 1, 1 being the upperleftmost cell.
```

To refresh that value, use the `setValue` method as follows:

```
cell.setValue('CRYPTOFINANCE(value)');
```

When that String is entered into the sheet, it will automatically trigger `CRYPTOFINANCE()` and refresh.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I think for my purposes in this case, having my "refresh" in a custom menu item is much easier, I wouldn't want to have to enter a string into the sheet somewhere every time I wanted to refresh.  And in my case most cells contain a cryptofinance function, but not all, so copy/pasting all the data works better for me.

Comment: You don't need to enter a string anywhere, you simply attach this syntax to a function that's built into a sidebar or dialog.

Comment: Hmmm I'm afraid I don't understand.  Sidebar or dialog?  Attaching syntax to a function...?  I don't know what those mean.

Comment: Use GAS + JS and HTML to create a sidebar add-on that contains a button that refreshes the selected cells.

Comment: Ah ok, that's all beyond me at this time and I don't really want to go down the rabbit hole for this.  I appreciate the suggestion anyway.